# Defining dynamically allocated global device array in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, dynamic-arrays

So I want a device array that is dynamically allocated based on some host variable. This array should be visible to all device functions hence the global scope.

I decided to make the use of cudaMemcpyToSymbol by defining a global device pointer and attaching a value onto it later on from the host code.

```
const int k = 10;
__device__ int *divi;

void func()
{
   int data[k] = {1,2,3}; //so the first three values are 1,2,3 and the rest are zero
   cudaMemcpyToSymbol("divi", data, k*sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}

__global__ void kernel()
{
   //do something with the divi array
}

int main()
{
    func();
    kernel<<<1,128>>>();
}
```

Using CUDA error check functions returns a failure when the memory copy operation is performed. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for the buffer on the device (should be done before copying into it).

Comment: There is no way that code could compile. The string versions of the symbol APIs were deprecated and remove from CUDA at least 10 years ago. So unless you are using a truly ancient version of CUDA, there should warnings and all compiler errors which you are ignoring

Comment: @Areen did you try what I suggested in my answer below ?

Comment: @wohlstad Hey, for some reason I have not been able to add a comment since you answered the question, neither have I been able to accept the answer for some reason. But I specified a memory buffer to the code and it works now. I realized the mistake that I was making thank you for your help and advice.

Comment: Oh surprisingly adding a comment and accepting the answer finally works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't allocated memory for the device buffer  before copying into it.
[`cudaMalloc`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356) can be used for that.
You also need to free the device buffers eveuntually, with a matching call to [`cudaFree`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ga042655cbbf3408f01061652a075e094).

Another issue is that you can avoid having a global device pointer (and size), and pass them to the kernel as agruments.

The code below demonstrates it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"


__global__ void kernel(int * pDataDevice, size_t dataSize)
{
    // Print just for a debug test, assuming array has at least 5 elements:
    // (Note that in your final code it is better to avoids prints from within a kernel).
    printf("thread %d, data: %d %d %d %d %d ...\n", threadIdx.x, pDataDevice[0], pDataDevice[1], pDataDevice[2], pDataDevice[3], pDataDevice[4]);

    // Do something with the pDataDevice array
}


int main()
{
    const size_t k = 10;
    int dataHost[k] = { 1,2,3 }; // The first three values are 1,2,3 and the rest are zero
    int* pDataDevice = nullptr;

    // Allocate device buffer and copy into it:
    cudaMalloc(&pDataDevice, k * sizeof(dataHost[0]));  // TODO: Check return code and handle errors.
    cudaMemcpy(pDataDevice, dataHost, k * sizeof(dataHost[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // TODO: Check return code and handle errors.

    // Run the kernel:
    kernel << <1, 128 >> > (pDataDevice, k);

    // Free device buffer:
    cudaFree(pDataDevice);      // TODO: Check return code and handle errors.
}
```

All the cuda functions return a [`cudaError_t`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g3f51e3575c2178246db0a94a430e0038) status code which I ignore in my code above to keep things simple.
In your actual code you should check it and handle errors accordingly.